# Why am I getting the method isEmpty() is undefined for the type StringBuilder

Tags: java

Why am I getting the method isEmpty() is undefined for the type StringBuilder?

```java
StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
if (bikeSearchBo.getModelName() != null && bikeSearchBo.getModelName().trim().length() > 0) {
    whereClause.append(whereClause.isEmpty() ? " where bike_model_nm =:modelName" : "or bike_model_nm=:modelName");
    mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("modelName", bikeSearchBo.getModelName());
}
```

Comment: How are you importing `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Beacuse ```StringBuilder``` does not have ```isEmpty``` method. You can use ```stringBuffer.length()==0```. And  the reason why there is no such method is: ```StringBuilder``` is typically used locally for accumulating/editing string data and not used as a value.  See: [JDK-8181398](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8181398)

Comment: which version of Java are you using? In Java 15 `StringBuilder` has `isEmpty` via `CharSequence`.

Comment: Voting to re-open this Question. The Question is specific and valid, and has a specific cause and solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Requires Java 15+

The [`CharSequence#isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#isEmpty()) method inherited by `StringBuilder` was added in Java 15.

To call `StringBuilder#isEmpty`, you must be using Java 15 or later.

Be aware that 15 and 16 are at end-of-life. Java 17 is a Long-Term Support (LTS) version.

To figure out this sort of problem, examine the Javadoc. Classes and methods are marked with their first Java version by the label *Since:*.